How to display jUnit tags as a part of surefire report?
I am automating my test-cases using jUnit and I want to categorize it to some specific modules. Now, after I run the test-cases, I'm getting surefire reports. I want to filter those test-cases by the tags (i.e; login flow, registration flow) etc. I have provided the filters like below using jUnit.
@Test
@Tag("LoginFlow")
Using jUnit Jupiter 5.8.2
I want to see how many test-cases are of LoginFlow and how many are of Registration flow - Based on the tags (However I can do via folder/classes, but in this requirement, I want it by Tags as we are using this tags in different folders/classes and packages)

Have a look at the Launcher API. It can produce a test plan that you can inspect programatically, including tags. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api
